# Difference between Quantile and Percentile generated in R

Tags: r, dplyr, quantile

Please excuse my math, but why is the result from these 2 codes different? Was expecting the expense in the row of 63 and 82 cumulative percentage for year 2015 to be the same as the expense generated by the second. First being 0.591 for X63, and 0.858 for X82, and the second code in cumsum_pct shows 0.792, and 0.966 respectively. Thanks

```
set.seed(1)
library('dplyr')
Claims6 <- data.frame(year = factor(rep(c(2015, 2016), each = 10)),Expense = runif(20))

Claims6 %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  do(data.frame(t(quantile(.$Expense, probs = c(0.10, 0.30, 0.63, 0.82)))))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   year [2]
# year    X10.  X30.  X63.  X82.
# <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2015  0.0488 0.439 0.591 0.858
# 2 2016  0.101  0.262 0.592 0.805

Claims6 %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  arrange(year,Expense) %>%
  mutate(pct = round(Expense / sum(Expense),2),
         cumsum_pct = round(cumsum(Expense) / sum(Expense),2))

# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   year [2]
# year  Expense   pct cumsum_pct
# <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#   1 2015   0.0332  0.01       0.01
# 2 2015   0.0505  0.01       0.02
# 3 2015   0.384   0.07       0.09
# 4 2015   0.463   0.09       0.18
# 5 2015   0.467   0.09       0.26
# 6 2015   0.538   0.1        0.37
# 7 2015   0.617   0.12       0.48
# 8 2015   0.792   0.15       0.63
# 9 2015   0.966   0.18       0.82
# 10 2015   0.972   0.18       1   
# 11 2016   0.0622  0.01       0.01
# 12 2016   0.106   0.02       0.03
# 13 2016   0.178   0.04       0.07
# 14 2016   0.298   0.06       0.13
# 15 2016   0.445   0.09       0.23
# 16 2016   0.591   0.12       0.35
# 17 2016   0.592   0.12       0.47
# 18 2016   0.765   0.16       0.63
# 19 2016   0.872   0.18       0.81
# 20 2016   0.904   0.19       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two related, but separate, summary stats. The first relates to ordering, the 2nd relates to cumulative sum. They will cover the same range of values, but with different weighting of the elements.

In the simpler example below, the first calc using `quantile` relates to sampling, showing that the 50% sample is a 2, halfway between the 2nd and 3rd values. You'd get the same median value even if the first and/or last values were more extreme -- `quantile` only cares about the order.

The second is the cumulative distribution of the values, showing that the 50% cumulative sum is at 3.

```
nums = c(0, 1, 3, 4) 
quantile(nums)
#   0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
# 0.00 0.75 2.00 3.25 4.00 

data.frame(nums = nums) %>%   
    mutate(pct = nums / sum(nums),
           cumsum_pct = cumsum(pct))
#    nums  pct cumsum_pct
# 1    0 0.000      0.000
# 2    1 0.125      0.125
# 3    3 0.375      0.500
# 4    4 0.500      1.000
```

Similarly, your numbers will not generally match between the two calculations you provided, since they do different things. The `quantile` one tells the value at a given fraction of the way through the list of ordered elements, while the other tells the value when the cumulative sum has reached the given fraction of the total.